# How do I make my button, sort the numbers inputted by a user in a descending way, as it only does ascending

Tags: python, sorting

so I have my code working for a Selection Sort with a GUI and wanted to add in a button "Sort Descending" which will order the numbers from largest to smallest. Thanks please help! This is for a school project hence the functions being longer etc.

````
#Variable of the array
A = []
#Add Function
def add():
    global label_result
    newNumber = int(passwordEntry.get())
    A.append(newNumber)
    label_result = tk.Label(master, text=str(A))
    label_result.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)
#Sort Function
def sort(A):
    #Sets the comparison number - The book from demonstration
    for i in range(len(A)):
        # Find the minimum element in remaining
        # unsorted array
        minimum = i
        #The septre from demonstration (what its being compared to)
        for j in range(i+1, len(A)):
            #The stop sign (the lowest number out of the remainding numbers)
            if A[minimum] > A[j]:
                minimum = j

        # Swap the found minimum element with
        # the first element
        A[i], A[minimum] = A[minimum], A[i]
    label_msg['text'] = "Sorted"
    label_result['text'] = str(A)

master = tk.Tk()
master.title("Dans Selection Sort")
passwordEntry = tk.Entry(master)
passwordEntry.grid(row=0, column=1)
tk.Label(master, text='Enter Number: ', font='bold',).grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Button(master, text='Add to Array', command=add).grid(row=1, column=0)
#lambda allows you to call a function with parameter.
tk.Button(master, text='Sort Ascending', command=lambda: sort(A)).grid(row=1, column=1)
tk.Button(master, text='Sort Descending', command=lambda: sort(A)).grid(row=1, column=2)
label_msg = tk.Label(master, text='')
label_msg.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)```
````

Answer (score 0):

1. You can pass in a compare function, i.e.:

greater_than = lambda a, b: a > b

```
def sort(A, compare):
   ...
   if compare(A[minimum], A[j]):
      ...
```

Change your compare function to get a different ordering.

2. You can also pass in a reverse boolean like the standard functions:

```
def sort(A, reverse=False):
  ...
  if (A[minimum] < A[j] and not reverse) or (not A[minimum] < A[j] and reverse):
     ...
```

3. You could leave the function as is, and just reverse the resulting array:

```
sort(A)
A = A[::-1]
```

4. Use `list.sort(reverse=True)`.
5. Use `list = sorted(list, reverse=True)`.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, so do i have to do all of them or just one? If just one which exact line do I put the "reverse=False" etc.

Comment: Just one.  If your exercise requires you to write your own sort, then option 2 would be the easiest.  Change  sort method signature and replace, the line "if A[minimum] > A[j]:" with the one in the answer.  I swapped the order to be asc (like usual, btw).  If you need descending, then change the calls to sort from `.sort(A)` to `.sort(A, reverse=True)`

Comment: A = [1,5,2]. A.sort(reverse=True).  A = sorted(A, reverse=True). Yeah, mixed up syntax.  These are standard sort functions see https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html.  Yeah, and your sort function doesn't return anything, so you would need to do sort(A) then A = A[::-1]

Comment: Yeah, your sort(A) doesn't return anything.  Updated my answer.